# How can I set a default sequence generator for ALL domain classes in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, generator, sequence

I know that I can set the sequence generation of the identifier for ONE domain class using the id mapping (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html). However I cannot find a way to set this for ALL domain classes.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a (undocumented?) way of setting the default:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = { 'id'(generator: 'uuid') }
```

Comment: Ok, so can you give a link?

Comment: My comment is a link. Hover over it and click.